# Combining two string with dot (.) in PHP

Tags: php, string, syntax

I got error on this,

```
$variable = "path";
$path = "D:\".$variable.".txt";
```

I wanted it to echo $path like this,

```
D:\path.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: by using a \ you are escaping the " ... use this `$path = "D:\\".$variable.".txt";`

Comment: When you use backslash (\) PHP reads that next character will be escaped. Try this with double backslash: `$path = "D:\\".$variable.".txt";` @rjre11211994

Comment: Your problem is `"D:\"..... you're effectively escaping the `"`; use `"D:\\".` to escape the `\\` isntead

Comment: This is effectively a typo - even the StackOverflow syntax highlighter shows you what the problem is - the \" escapes the " in the string (the bits in red are "in the string" those in black "outside".  You need: `$path = "D:\\".$variable.".txt";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You accidentally escaped the quote. Change your code to the following. Also, it is a good idea to adopt better spacing for better readability of your programs.

```
$variable = "path";
$path = "D:\\" . $variable . ".txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to concatenate in your case. Below trick will give your desired output.

```
$variable = "path";
$path = "D:\$variable.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use \:

```
<?php
$variable = "path";
echo $path = "D:\\".$variable.".txt";
?>
```